# How to use log4j in gradle task

Tags: logging, groovy, log4j, gradle

I'm new to gradle. I tried using log4j annotation. The log statements are working fine with simpe Groovy file. But when i try to use them with gradle task. It is not getting printed.

Groovy file :

> ```
>   @Log4j
> class HelloWorldLog {
>    static void main(args) {
>        log.info "Hello world"
>     }
>  }
> ```

Gradle task:

> ```
>    @Log4j
>     class DeployTask extends DefaultTask {
>        @TaskAction
>        def deployTaskAction(){
>             log.info "DeployTask!!!"
>        }
>    }
> ```

and i use same log4j.properties file for both.
The logs are getting printed in console and not on log file. How to redirect logs to log file?

Thanks

Comment: Would Gradle's [own logger](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/logging.html) suite your needs?

Comment: No.. It is printing the logs to the console. But i want it to be redirected to log file. Is there any possible way ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the `log4j.properties` as a classpath configuration? For deployments I do this all through Jenkins (ldap, audit trail, etc). The job builds with Gradle and deploys with fabric. This was more work to setup, but worked out very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Save your log4j.properties file in `src/main/resources` and build your project.

Add this line:

```
war.from('src/main/resources'){ include('log4j.properties')}
```

to your main gradle.build. Then build it again and run.

Answer (score 0):

Put `log4j.properties` with following contents in classpath (may be src/main/resources):

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\myLog.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```